# Separate data in a cell in to multiple columns

Tags: excel

As title, I would like to separate data in a cell into multiple columns.
I have no idea how to do it in excel. I was wondering if anyone can help.
Otherwise, I'll do it with Python.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XutiS.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNG9.png)

Comment: This seems more like multiple lines than multiple columns.  Multiple columns is easier, check out the SEARCH, MID, LEFT, RIGHT and LEN functions.  You want to split on either LINEFEED (char(10)) or CARRIAGERETURN (char(13)) depending on what OS you're on.

Comment: Use `TEXT to Columns` method from DATA tab.